# Find the equation of the plane parallel to the plane determined by points A, B and C, and passing through the point D

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vectors

> Find the equation of the plane parallel to the plane determined by points A, B and C, and passing through the point D

$A(0,0,0)$

$B(1,2,3)$

$C(-3,0,0)$

$D(-1,2,4)$

$\overrightarrow{AB} = <1,2,3>$

$\overrightarrow{AC} = <-3,0,0>$

Since $\overrightarrow{AB} \times \overrightarrow{AC} = -9j + 6k$

Is it true that equation of the plane parallel is:

$-9(y-2)+6(z-4)=0$

$-9y+6z=6$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the plan is given by ${\bf n}\cdot ({\bf x}-{\bf x_0})=0$

Since you found that ${\bf n}=<0,-9,6>$ the equation of the plane become
$$<0,-9,6>\cdot (<x,y,z>-(-1,2,4))=-9y+6z-6=0$$

That is $-9y+6z=6$ is the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my answer!  I was quite sure I had done something wrong but feels good to know that I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

the normal is $-9ck+6cj$, $c$ not $0$. Then the equation is $-9c(y-2)+6c(z-4)=0$. Now plug in $D$ to determine $c$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm confused by your comments.  What is c?